# Undefined variable $title in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting subject error on web hosting in regard to adding component in laravel, while same code is working on XAMPP. please guide what is the possible solution to it.

Component File *.php

```
    //Creating  title variable which is public
    public $title="";
    public function __construct($componentName)
    {
        $this->title=$componentName;
    }
```

Component file *.blade.php

```
<div>
    <h1 style="color:blueviolet;">Header from Component for page {{$title}}</h1>
</div>
```

Welcome File *.blade.php

```
<x-header componentName="Welcome Page" />
```

I am getting below error on webhosting

> Undefined variable $title

Comment: How are you returning the view in your controller?

Comment: I am not routing it through controller

Comment: How are you rendering the blade file?

Comment: I am rendering the file from Component File *.php
Code is as below.
'    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.header');
    }'